# Plotly width larger than content

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, plotly, ggplotly

I'm using Plotly (ggplotly) in my rmarkdown file. The width of the plot is larger than the content, see attached screenshot.
As you can see the legend is outside the content.
Can I fix this using CSS, if so, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I had set a default fig.width and fig.height in knitr::opts_chunk() which caused this.